# T-SQL. Можно ли хранимой процедурой добавить нового пользователя базы данных?

Tags: sql-server

Реализую приложение в котором хочу вызывая процедуру через SqlCommand добавлять нового пользователя базы данных. Подскажите можно ли вообще это сделать?

Comment: Можно, но нужны большие права которые приложению редко даются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В SQL Server почти все можно сделать через SQL Command.

Во всех стандартных диалогах Management Studio есть кнопка "Script", которая генерирует скрипт для всех действий, которые вы сделали в диалоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для создания пользователя + маппинга пользователя на базу она геренирует:

```sql
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [SomeUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'test', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
USE [SomeDatabase]
GO
CREATE USER [SomeUser] FOR LOGIN [SomeUser]
GO
USE [SomeDatabase]
GO
ALTER USER [SomeUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
USE [SomeDatabase]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [SomeUser]
GO
```

Соответственно, вам нужно выполнить две команды. Одну - на базе master (подправив по необходимости):

```sql
CREATE LOGIN [SomeUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'test', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

Вторую - на той базе, к которой нужно дать доступ (можно выполнить одним вызовом SqlCommand):

```sql
CREATE USER [SomeUser] FOR LOGIN [SomeUser]
ALTER USER [SomeUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [SomeUser]
```